# Is it ok to tell jokes?

Tags: halal-haram

I have read a Hadith but I don't remember it perfectly that we should not make people laugh by telling a lie.so is it permissible to tell a joke?

Comment: Presumably the hadith you're thinking of is [Sunan Abi Dawud 4990](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/218): "Woe to him who tells things, speaking falsely, to make people laugh thereby. Woe to him! Woe to him!." or a variant thereof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://islamqa.info/en/answers/22170/conditions-of-permissible-joking

Comment: Listen to some Mufti Menk talks on YouTube. You will learn about comedy easily done by a Mufti. Just analyze his comedy and you will come to your conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Good Sense of humor is a indication of healthy mind. Prophet Muhammad PBUH also told jokes like:

HE said to old women no old people will go in heaven. The woman start crying then He said because old people will become young in heaven. This is just telling the truth in a way that becomes humorous.
So the jokes shouldnt have lie or humiliation for others because it can hurt other's feelings which is prohibited in Islam. This type of humor is from Low IQ or sick mind to just degrade others and for point scoring which is unfortunately very common in our society. Thats why there are lot of fights and separations in relationships.

HE had a great chemistry with Mother Ayesha RA. Why? because of HIS humorous and cheerful nature at home.

Comment: Let's take an example of a joke; Santa: what are you doing? Banta: recording baby voice. Santa: why? Banta: when he grows up.i will ask him what he meant by this.   There is no man like santa banta who said this ever.so is it not a lie ? Almost every joke is like this.

Comment: The humor i have mentioned is not a lie. Please read it again.

Comment: @Obaid The joke didn't contain a lie, It's the truth old people never go to paradise, instead they are turned young again.

Answer (score 0):

والسلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته
Yes it is. The Prophet himself told jokes. https://sunnah.com/shamail/35. Make sure jokes have no lies on them. Also, keep them nice and not bad.